# I'm writing a bash script for mongoDB document exportation, what's wrong with it?

Tags: bash, mongoexport

I'm trying to make a bash script that run over an array to export documents from a mongo database, but I'm not able to make my index to be incremented.

```
#!/bin/bash
#script de exportação de documentos das coleções

valores=( 2 4 8 22 40 43 47 48 53 54 55 57 58 60 68 69 74 77 84 86 95 99 107 111 118 122 136 138 139 141 149 150 154 155)

x=0

echo "esse script vai exportar as coisinhas, relaxe e aguarde"

while [ "$x" -lt "${#valores[@]}" ]; do
        echo "exportando o documento $x"
        mongoexport --db loginapp --collection projetos2017 --query {numInscricao:"${valores[$x]}"} --out premiados2017"$x".json
        $x=$((x+1)) 
done
```

Comment: I guess you received the error: `-bash: ...: command not found` where `...` is whatever your `$x=$((x+1))` expression would expanded to. You could post that error and not just `I'm not able to make my index to be incremented`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've already managed to solve my problem, the dollar sign is not used on variable declaration.

```
while [ "$x" -lt "${#valores[@]}" ]; do
        echo "exportando o documento $x"
        mongoexport --db loginapp --collection projetos2017 --query {numInscricao:"${valores[$x]}"} --out premiados2017"$x".json
        x=$((x+1)) 
done
```